# How to create Button click on the modern window theme page

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

How to create Button click on a modern window theme page. Here is the modern window them:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:modernui="clr-namespace:FirstFloor.ModernUI"
                xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Controls"
                xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Navigation">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/Button.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/Converters.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/TextBlock.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style TargetType="controls:ModernWindow">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundContent" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundContent}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource WindowText}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBorder}" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="800" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="640" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="320" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="320" />
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip" />
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ModernWindow">
                <Border x:Name="WindowBorder" Margin="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness}}">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="WindowBorderBackground" Color="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundColor}" />
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Border.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="BackgroundAnimation">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="WindowBorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundColor}" Duration="0:0:.6" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </Border.Resources>

                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <AdornerDecorator>
                            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="36" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <!-- window background content -->
                                <ContentControl Grid.RowSpan="5" Content="{TemplateBinding BackgroundContent}" />
                                <!-- title bar -->
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="96" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <!-- title -->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" Margin="8,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ModernWindowTitle}"
                                               DataContext="{TemplateBinding IsTitleVisible}"
                                               Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

                                    <!-- title links -->
                                    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding TitleLinks}" Margin="0,0,24,0" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Line x:Name="Separator" X1=".5" Y1="3" X2=".5" Y2="12" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="{DynamicResource SeparatorBackground}" />

                                                    <Button Content="{Binding DisplayName}"
                                                            Command="navigation:LinkCommands.NavigateLink"
                                                            CommandParameter="{Binding Source}"
                                                            CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=ContentFrame}"
                                                            Style="{StaticResource SystemButtonLink}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Separator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                    <!-- userName -->
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="11"    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                               DataContext="{TemplateBinding AuthUserName}"   />
                                    <!-- logo (visible only when LogoData is not null) -->
                                    <Border Grid.Column="3" Background="{DynamicResource Accent}" Width="36" Height="36" Margin="8,0"
                                            DataContext="{TemplateBinding LogoData}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=inverse}">
                                        <Path Data="{Binding}" Stretch="Fill" Fill="White" Width="24" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Border>

                                    <!-- window system buttons-->
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                                        <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="{x:Static modernui:Resources.Minimize}" Style="{StaticResource SystemButton}">
                                            <Button.Content>
                                                <Grid Width="13" Height="12" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,0,1">
                                                    <Path Data="M0,6 L8,6 Z" Width="8" Height="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                          Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="2"  />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Button.Content>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Grid Margin="1,0,1,0">
                                            <Button x:Name="Restore" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="{x:Static modernui:Resources.Restore}" Style="{StaticResource SystemButton}" Visibility="Collapsed" >
                                                <Button.Content>
                                                    <Grid Width="13" Height="12" UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,.5,.5">
                                                        <Path Data="M2,0 L8,0 L8,6 M0,3 L6,3 M0,2 L6,2 L6,8 L0,8 Z" Width="8" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                              Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="1"  />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Button.Content>
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button x:Name="Maximize" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="{x:Static modernui:Resources.Maximize}" Style="{StaticResource SystemButton}" >
                                                <Button.Content>
                                                    <Grid Width="13" Height="12">
                                                        <Path Data="M0,1 L9,1 L9,8 L0,8 Z" Width="9" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                              Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="2"  />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Button.Content>
                                            </Button>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}}" ToolTip="{x:Static modernui:Resources.Close}" Style="{StaticResource SystemCloseButton}" >
                                            <Button.Content>
                                                <Grid Width="13" Height="12" RenderTransform="1,0,0,1,0,1">
                                                    <Path Data="M0,0 L8,7 M8,0 L0,7 Z" Width="8" Height="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                          Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" StrokeThickness="1.5"  />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Button.Content>
                                        </Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>

                                <!--<Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="42" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    --><!-- back button --><!--
                                    <controls:ModernButton Margin="8,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                           EllipseDiameter="24" IconWidth="12" IconHeight="12"
                                                           IconData="F1 M 33,22L 33,26L 19.75,26L 27,33L 20.5,33L 11,24L 20.5,15L 27,15L 19.75,22L 33,22 Z"
                                                           Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseBack"
                                                           CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=ContentFrame}" 
                                                           ToolTip="{x:Static modernui:Resources.Back}"
                                                           WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />

                                    --><!-- main menu --><!--
                                    <controls:ModernMenu Grid.Column="1"
                                                         SelectedSource="{Binding Source, ElementName=ContentFrame, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                         LinkGroups="{TemplateBinding MenuLinkGroups}" />
                                </Grid>-->

                                <!-- content frame -->
                                <controls:ModernFrame x:Name="ContentFrame" KeepContentAlive="False" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="3,3,3,3" Source="{Binding ContentSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" ContentLoader="{TemplateBinding ContentLoader}"/>
                                <!-- resize grip -->
                                <Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ResizeGrip" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" WindowChrome.ResizeGripDirection="BottomRight">
                                    <Path Width="12" Height="12" Margin="1" 
                                          Stroke="{DynamicResource WindowText}"
                                          StrokeThickness="1"
                                          Stretch="None"
                                          Data="F1 M1,10 L3,10 M5,10 L7,10 M9,10 L11,10 M2,9 L2,11 M6,9 L6,11 M10,9 L10,11 M5,6 L7,6 M9,6 L11,6 M6,5 L6,7 M10,5 L10,7 M9,2 L11,2 M10,1 L10,3" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Border>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBorderActive}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                        <Setter TargetName="Maximize" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Restore" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="LayoutRoot" Property="Margin" Value="7" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Normal">
                        <Setter TargetName="Maximize" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Restore" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip" />
                            <Condition Property="WindowState" Value="Normal" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ResizeGrip" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <WindowChrome CornerRadius="0" GlassFrameThickness="1" UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" NonClientFrameEdges="None" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

> We Need to button on the top header of the modern window and click or command of the button. I want to do some implementation on this command. How to make command here?

Comment: Please provide less and more specific code

Comment: what is unclear, I have put  xaml of  of ModernWindow.xaml in the above question. And I want to use button control on this  page  header and I want to make command of the button. how to make command of this button? 
If you idea have FirstFloor.ModernUI then you can understand easily.

Comment: To answer your question you need to create new template for the ModernUI Window and apply it.